# SUMPRODUCT, LEFT, MID and empty cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010

My excel spreadsheet has a W column which has values which look like this:

```
<blank>
<blank>
001      2 <various superfluous spaces>
<blank>
001      5 <various superfluous spaces>
002      6 <various superfluous spaces>
<blank>
```

I'm trying to add up the numbers listed at the right if the first 3 numbers match a certain criteria. I'm currently trying this formula, but it's not working:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($W$2:$W$5000;3)="001");MID($W$2:$W$5000;9;2))
```

It incorrectly results in 0. Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Enter as array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

```
=SUM(IF((LEFT($A$1:$A$4,3)="001")*(NOT(ISBLANK($A$1:$A$4))),--MID($A$1:$A$4,9,2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited: again**

How about this...

`=SUMPRODUCT(IF(LEFT(W2:W5000;3)="001";1;0);IFERROR(VALUE(MID(W2:W5000;9;2));0))`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, @Tony. Unfortunately this still results in a 0.

Comment: Hmmm.  Works for me with the input you suggest. Can you _temporarily_ add a column to test `=IF(LEFT(W2;3)="001";1;0)`, `=IF(LEFT(W3;3)="001";1;0)`, etc?  And the same for `=IFERROR(VALUE(TRIM(W2))`...?  If you don't get numeric outputs in all cases, that might throw some light on the problem.

Comment: I've added 2 temporary helper columns. The left one - =IF(LEFT(W2;3)="001";1;0) - seems to be working fine, showing a 1 when it's true. But the secondary - =IFERROR(VALUE(TRIM(W2));0) - always results in a 0.

Comment: You have probably picked this up already, but I have edited the answer slightly to reflect that the `trim` expression should apply to the second column (not `W`).  If that doesn't fix it, I might have to admit defeat.

Comment: I see. So it should trim the helper column. But to what purpose? It will only show a 0 or 1, i.e. true/false? Its the second part of the column that I need, i.e. that I could get with MID($W$2:$W$5000;9;2) (from 9th position, first 2 characters)

Comment: I misunderstood.  I assumed you had two columns to begin with.  I have altered the answer again.  Fourth time lucky?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting a 0. Just =IFERROR(VALUE(MID(W2:W5000;9;2));0) in the helper column gives a 0 as well.

Comment: You could try: =SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($W$2:$W$5000,3)="001"),--(MID($W$2:$W$5000,9,2)&0))/10. Also, are you certain that performing this MID operation with such static parameters will be certain of capturing ALL values at the end of your strings? I can give you a more flexible, generic version if not.

Comment: Thank you @XOR-LX. That works perfectly! It will capture all needed values so this solution will work 100%.

Comment: @XOR-LX: One more question. What if I want to check for 2 conditions? I.e. every record starting with 001 or 002?

Comment: You can use: =SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT($W$2:$W$10,3),{"001","002"},0))),--(MID($W$2:$W$10,9,2)&0))/10 and then amend the contents of the array {"001","002"} as and when to suit your needs. If the number of elements in this array is subject to change, or likely to become large, even better would be to list those values in the actual worksheet somewhere, e.g. X2:X3, after which the formula becomes: =SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT($W$2:$W$10,3),$X$2:$X$3,0))),--(MID($W$2:$W$10,9,2)&0))/10.

Comment: That one wasn't too difficult: =SUMPRODUCT(--((LEFT($W$2:$W$5000,3)="001")+(LEFT($W$2:$W$5000,3)="002")),--(MID($W$2:$W$5000,9,2)&0))/10

Comment: Yes. If it's only ever going to be two criteria then that is also a perfectly fine option. Bit unwieldy if it becomes more than two, which is why I gave you the alternative.

Comment: @XOR-LX Thanks! I can't mark your feedback as answer, I think. Since you're commenting to Tony's answer. If you want the mark, you can post it separately.

Comment: I guess I'll live without :-) Unless the site's admin want me to proceed as such for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to add an additional column (say `y`), you can do something like this:

```
   W       | X | Y
1  <blank> |   | =if(isblank(w1), 0, if(len(w1)>2, if(left(w1,3)=="001", 
                           int(X1), 0), 0))
2  <blank> |   | ... copy down above...            
3  001     | 2
4  <blank> | 
5  001     | 5
6  002     | 6
7  <blank> | 
...
n          |   | = sum(y1:y...)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Unfortunately I cannot add any columns.